# In Interstellar, did the people from plan A and plan B intermix?

Tags: interstellar

We know at the end of the movie

> Cooper left the Plan A facility in a small fighter craft, and presumably went to Edmund's Planet to spend his life with Brand.   Glad for him, but this question is not about him.

What I'm trying to understand is, was there regular immigration, visitation, trade, etc. between A and B.  That would certainly have an effect on the mission at B to repopulate the species and restore technology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this character going at the end of Interstellar?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73019/where-is-this-character-going-at-the-end-of-interstellar)

Comment: It's not entirely clear where Coop is going at the end of the film.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not asking for Coop's fate, I'm asking whether the two colonies *generally* fraternized or not.

Comment: This pre-supposes that the wormhole is still there. There's some evidence that it's not; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73393/is-the-wormhole-still-open/104246#104246

Comment: it also presupposes that there are two colonies. Plan B was always the real "plan A" - meaning, it was the only one expected to work. Plan A only actually worked because of the events of the film, thus negating the need or existence of a true Plan B colony (of which, it seems only Brand remains)

Comment: you could have said "Re**cooper**ate" the species, but you missed that chance!

Comment: I don't see how these could possibly be dupes

Comment: @Edlothiad - Because the question of whether coop (and indeed any other member of Plan A) was able to re-use the wormhole is integral to the answer.

Comment: @Valorum it's a prerequisite, but does not answer the question unless the wormhole is closed, in which case "nope".   I have my doubts that only a transcendent, evolved supersociety could create a wormhole, but a naked ape could uncreate it.

Comment: @Harper - They also closed it

Comment: Without additional information outside of the movie, there is no answer to this question.

Comment: @JackBNimble or book or writer/director comments.